# Помогите создать обработчик нажатой кнопки в TELEGRAM

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Учусь создавать чат-боты в Telegramm. 
Получилось создать кнопки из списка, но не получается обработчик нажатых кнопок создать. Цель чтобы при нажатии кнопок из списка, вылазило сообщение с этим как раз названием самой кнопки. Помогите пожалуйста!!!!!

```
answers = []
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def inline_key(a):
    if a.text == "/start":
        js = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        js_btns = []
        for i, answer in enumerate(answers):
            js_btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=answer, callback_data=str(i)))
        js.add(*js_btns)
        bot.send_message(a.chat.id, 'Здравствутйте! Что будем читать?', reply_markup=js)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    query = callback_query
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, show_alert=False, text="Вы выбрали"+ query)
```

Comment: А откуда в `query = callback_query` взялась `callback_query`?

Comment: Да это я просто перебирал из других вариантов и до такой степени вот намудил.

Comment: В `call.data` должен быть текст той кнопки: https://github.com/MasterGroosha/telegram-tutorial/blob/master/lesson_08/bot.py#L23

Comment: Ничего пока не получилось сделать...

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть строка, содержащая литералы Python, такие как строки, float и т. д., Вы можете использовать `ast.literal_eval` для оценки ее значения.
Это добавляет возможность разрешать только определенный синтаксис.

таким образом, используя `ast.literal_eval` мы можем получить номер нажатой кнопки:

`answers = ['123', '456', '789']`

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    print(ast.literal_eval(call.data))
>>> 0  # нажали кнопку 123
>>> 1  # нажали кнопку 456
>>> 2  # нажали кнопку 789
```

используя `ast.literal_eval(call.data)` как индекс для `answers` мы получим объект списка:

```
print(answers[int(ast.literal_eval(call.data))])
>>> 456  # при нажатии на кнопку '456'
```

собираем всё вместе:

```
import ast    
bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, show_alert=False, text="Вы выбрали" + answers[int(ast.literal_eval(call.data))])
```

Comment: ответ исправлен

Comment: Спасибо, всё так просто оказалось. Скажите пожалуйста, если в боте будут другие кнопки из другого меню, то как сделать так, чтобы хендлер мог различать какие именно кнопки нажимаются?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как решение, пожалуйста. "Хендлер различает кнопки" по callback_data, а условия будут if call.data == 'то что написано в callback_data'.