# Телеграм бот. Как скрыть данные

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть телеграмм бот, мне нужно отправить некоторые данные в сообщении не показывая те данные пользователю.

Я использую pyTelegramBotAPI.

```
sticker_info = message.sticker
    inline_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Download the sticker", callback_data="sticker"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Download sticker pack", callback_data="pack"),
    )
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Information about the sticker:\n"
        + f"file id: {sticker_info.file_id}\n"
        + f"emoji: {sticker_info.emoji}\n"
        + f"set name: {sticker_info.set_name}",
        reply_markup=inline_markup,
    )
```

мне нужно отправить `sticker_info.file_id` `sticker_info.set_name` чтобы юзер не видел

Как я могу ето зделать??

Comment: А какой смысл? Для чего вы тогда это вообще отправляете?

Comment: @MyZik чтоб скачать либо пак либо один стикер

Comment: Сохраняйте в переменную, базу данных, кэш или скачивайте сразу. В чём проблема?

Comment: Ну а как можно передать, мне интересно, можно ли так зделать

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу конкретно, ваш процесс. Что, когда и куда скачиваться должно?

Comment: 1)Юзер присилает стикер боту  2)бот присилает сообщение(где есть стикер ид)(но мне не нужно стикер ид в етом сообщении, я хочу чтоб он передавался в колбек по другому как то) и две кнопки(скачать пак либо один стикер) 3) я беру етот стикер ид, и скачую по нему стикер

Comment: развивайте тему с callback_data - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1114375/234134